# Saving file in vim causes window to be empty

Tags: vim

I'm having trouble saving a file in vim. After I save it, the window becomes empty, as if it lost the file. The title on the tab reads

```
_highlight.sass, in `box-shadow`
```

The file does save with the changes I've made. But it's annoying having to reopen it every time. Saving other files does work fine. It's only this one file, and I don't know why.

Here are the file contents
https://gist.github.com/0f29da34719075bdc686

I found that opening two tabs of the file, saving one makes the tab not go empty when I save it. But it does lose syntax highlighting.

Comment: Are you running vim as root? Are you saving with `:w`? If you do a `:redraw!` after the window goes blank does it reappear?

Comment: Not running as root. If I do `:redraw!` it doesn't reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely to have some weird autocommand (or, more likely, bug in plugin(s) which help you work with sass (if I understood correctly) file) on `BufWrite(Pre|Cmd|Post)?` event. Try doing

```
debug w
```

and do `s<CR>` then `<CR>` `<CR>` `<CR>` until you see what causes the issue. After you got it `verbose autocmd [group] [Event [pattern]]` will help you determine where it was defined.

If you are familiar with debugging, there is also `n<CR>` which stands for `next` (`s<CR>` is `step`). May be useful to do `s<CR>` once (until you should see the first autocommand then), then `n<CR>` `<CR>` `<CR>` … Plain `<CR>` repeats previous debug action if debugging command was what you ran previously.

Comment: Thanks. It was the syntastic plugin. For some reason something in that sass file was causing it to freak out. It works correctly with other sass files.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your `~/.vimrc` file to something else and saving your code again. If this error does not happen anymore, then you have an autocommand messing stuff up and you need to debug like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822397/1536522

If the error still happens you might have a vim plugin causing issues: do you have anything in `~/.vim/`?